# Leaving ____ to ____ meaning

Tags: meaning, expressions

Can you please provide more example or perhaps a reference to usage of to leave as the following example?

> The founding fathers established constitutional protections for the
>   press because they understood that **leaving** the watchdog function to
>   partisan politicians wouldn’t necessarily serve the public interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definition 7 on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/leave)...

> **leave** - to let (a thing) remain for action or decision
>    *We **left** the details to the lawyer.*

In practice you can often (certainly in the cited example) replace ***leaving*** with ***entrusting***, but there's often (again, certainly in the cited example) an allusion to the underlying literal sense of ***abandoning*** (the oversight / watchdog function) to "less-than-trustworthy" politicians.

---

It's an idiomatically common usage in contexts like...

> *- I'm so worried! I just don't know what to do!*
>    *- **Leave it to me**. I'll sort everything out.*